# How to parse Json when the key is unknown using Python?

Tags: python, json

This is a sample of my Json:

```
text = {"rates":{
   "AT":{
     "country_name":"Austria",
     "standard_rate":20,
     "reduced_rates":{
       "food":10,
       "books":10
     }
  }
}}
```

Now the "AT" is the country code.. **It's not fixed**. It can also be GB, IT etc...

I want to parse this Json and get from it columns as follow:

```
rates.AT   rates.AT.country_name   rates.AT.reducted_rates.food
  AT           Austria                  10
```

Can be also renamed to:

```
code        country_name               food
  AT           Austria                  10
```

Say for example that in another run I have:

```
text = {"rates":{
   "IT":{
     "country_name":"Italy",
     "standard_rate":20,
     "reduced_rates":{
       "food":13,
       "books":11
     }
  }
}}
```

Then It needs to be:

```
rates.IT   rates.IT.country_name   rates.IT.reducted_rates.food
  IT           Italy                     13
```

Can be also renamed to:

```
 code        country_name               food
  IT           Italy                     13
```

How can I do this?

**EDIT:**

If possible using @GPhilo answer I would prefer to get the data as Pandas dataframe.
Something like?

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for k,item in dic['rates'].items(): # use iteritems() if you're on Python 2
    line = '{};{};{}'.format(k, item['country_name'], item['reduced_rates']['food'])
    df = df.append(line, ignore_index=True)
```

This doesn't work because line isn't the proper way to do this.

Comment: I understand that the key each time is unknown, but do you have a collections of keys? For example, "IT" for Italy, "US" for USA, "RU" for Russia etc are known to you?

Comment: __import__('json').loads(your_json_string)

Comment: What do you mean by time? The sample of data is what I get from the Json I just need to convert it to insert to columns in my DB

Comment: @karansthr print (json.loads(text)) gives  TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'dict'
  converting to string doesn't work either

Comment: you have to pass string not the dict

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once parsed, `json` objects are python `dict`s, so just loop over the key/value pair at the level you need and print the information:

```
import json

dic = json.loads('''
{"rates":{
   "AT":{
     "country_name":"Austria",
     "standard_rate":20,
     "reduced_rates":{
       "food":10,
       "books":10
     }
  }
}}
''')

for k,item in dic['rates'].items(): # use iteritems() if you're on Python 2
    print('{};{};{}'.format(k, item['country_name'], item['reduced_rates']['food']))
```

Format the output as needed, the three values you need are the three in the `format` call in the code above.
Running the sample returns:

```
AT;Austria;10
```

#### Edit: Amended the answer

Once parsed, json objects *are* python dicts: `print(dic.__class__)` returns `<class 'dict'>`.

#### Update

In reply to the edit in the question, instead of appending the formatted string, just append the values:

```
df = pd.Dataframe(columns=['code', 'country_name', 'food'])
[...]
df = df.append([k, item['country_name'], item['reduced_rates']['food']], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do json.dumps instead of print?

Comment: The print is just to show the three values you need to use. You can use `k, item['country_name'], item['reduced_rates']['food']` in any way you want, possibly manipulating them or formatting in a different way. If you update your answer with an example of how you want the output to be I can update the answer

Comment: TypeError: append() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'

Comment: sorry, the columns went in the Dataframe definition

Comment: I tried that it doesn't preduce the correct result all the code, country_name and food columns contains NaN and there is a 0 column with all the values

Comment: i solved it by  df = df.append({'A': i}, ignore_index=True)  according to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html  but it says that this is not efficient . What can I do?

Comment: Uhm interesting, I guess there's some formatting I'm missing, but good that you found the right way to make it work for you (would be nice if you could post the exact line you use in a comment or, better, edit my answer with the line that works for you so others coming here will have the working solution too). As per the efficiency, I guess it's due to the fact that appending line-by-line is inefficient, but in your case I don't see a way around that (and also, don't worry about efficiency until it is an actual issue to you)

Answer (score 3):

you should use `dict.keys()` to get a list of all keys of a dictionary, and then you can iterate it and do whatever you need with it.
For example:

```
for k in text.keys():
   #do something with text[k] or k itself
```

consider also use `dict.items()` to get pairs of key, value:

```
for k, v in text.items():
    #do something with k and v, where text[k] is v
```

that's good for python 3, in python 2 you should use `dict.iteritems()`